# Function that returns the magnitude of a 3 dimensional vector in c

Tags: c, function

I'm trying to write a program that finds the magnitude of a 3D vector. I need to use a function to find the magnitude (the program also finds the dot product of two vectors, but I'm just working on the magnitude part right now). The program first asks the user if they want to find the dot product or the magnitude, and when the user selects magnitude, it asks for 3 values for a vector. However, it returns the wrong thing. If I enter `1,2,3` as the components of the vector, it returns `292044616`. I think the problem is in my function call, but I'm now sure what it is. This is my code:

```c
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    double find_magnitude(double v1, double v2, double v3);

    //double theta;
    int v1, v2, v3;// w1, w2, w3, mag, dot;
    char a;

    //dot = (v1 * w1) + (v2 * w2) + (v3 * w3);

    printf("Enter M/m or magnitude or D/d for the dot product and angle in degrees: ");
    scanf("%c", &a);

    if (a == 'M' || a == 'm') {
        printf("Enter in values for v1, v2, and v3: ");
        scanf("%d,%d,%d", &v1, &v2, &v3);
        printf("%d", find_magnitude(v1, v2, v3));
    }

    return(0);
}

double find_magnitude(double v1, double v2, double v3) {
    double mag;
    mag = sqrt(pow(v1, 2) + pow(v2, 2) + pow(v3, 2));
    return(mag);
}
```

Comment: `%d` is not the right format specifier for `double`

Comment: BTW, "magnitude" is a square root of a dot product of vector with itself, so the right order would be to implement dot product, then reuse it for magnitude.

Comment: _Side note:_ Although it _is_ legal to put a function forward declaration at function scope (e.g.  `find_magnitude` _inside_ `main`), it is _much_ more idiomatic/useful to put it at _file_ scope. Otherwise, if you had _multiple_ functions that needed the forward declaration, then the declaration would have to be replicated multiple times [in each function]--a source for error. Move the `double find_magnitude(double v1, double v2, double v3);` in `main` to file scope _above_ `main` (e.g. _before_ the `int main(void)` line).

Comment: For future reference, since C99 there is also [hypot()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/hypot), which computes the magnitude of a 2D vector. Chaining two `hypot()` calls can be used to compute the magnitude of a 3D vector.

Comment: @Eph: very good point. Too bad C23 did not add `hypot3` for 3D vectors. C++ has 3 argument overloaded versions available since C++17 and even template versions from C++23 on.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is very simple: the function `find_magnitude` returns a `double` but you tell `printf` to convert an `int` with `%d`. You should instead use the `%f` format specifier:

```
printf("%f\n", find_magnitude(v1, v2, v3));
```

Note also these remarks:

- the forward declaration for `find_magnitude()` should be put at the global scope for consistency. As declared, the definition and declaration are independent and inconsistencies would not produce a diagnostic at compile time but would have undefined behavior at runtime. For this and other reasons, it is considered safer and idiomatic in C to always write declarations of global objects at global scope.
- the variables `v1`, `v2` and `v3` should probably be defined as `double`.
- `v1 * v1` is a simpler and more efficient way to compute the square of `v1` than `pow(v1, 2)`.
- the return value of `scanf()` should be tested to detect invalid or missing input.

Here is a modified version:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double find_magnitude(double v1, double v2, double v3);

int main(void) {
    double v1, v2, v3;
    char a;

    printf("Enter M/m or magnitude or D/d for the dot product and angle in degrees: ");
    if (scanf("%c", &a) != 1)
        return 1;

    if (a == 'M' || a == 'm') {
        printf("Enter in values for v1, v2, and v3: ");
        if (scanf("%lf,%lf,%lf", &v1, &v2, &v3) == 3) {
            printf("magnitude: %f\n", find_magnitude(v1, v2, v3));
        } else {
            printf("invalid input\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

double find_magnitude(double v1, double v2, double v3) {
    double mag;
    mag = sqrt(v1 * v1 + v2 * v2 + v3 * v3);
    return mag;
}
```

As commented by *Eph*, computing the magnitude (or modulus) of a 3D vector can be performed more accurately with the `hypot()` function declared in `<math.h>`:

- in case the values of `v1`, `v2` and/or `v3` are very large, very small or very different in magnitude, computing `sqrt(v1 * v1 + v2 * v2 + v3 * v3)` may produce inaccurate results.
- `hypot(v1, v2)` should be used in place of `sqrt(v1 * v1 + v2 * v2)` for 2D vectors and
- `hypot(v1, hypot(v2, v3))` for 3D vectors.

Here is a modified version of `find_magnitude`:

```
double find_magnitude(double v1, double v2, double v3) {
    return hypot(v1, hypot(v2, v3));
}
```